# Picking Ad Mob Mediation Networks 2015

Tags: optimization, admob

Looking to setup network mediation on AdMob.

There are a lot of networks on the list - so I'm looking for some sort of comparison of the networks or recommendations on setting up mediation such as: how many networks to use etc...

I plan to utilize simple 320x50 ad banner and possibly interstitials on app exit.

To not keep it open ended and in a form of a question/answer, please provide brief explanation/reasoning for your recommendations.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- MillenialMedia - Pretty decent engineering. Pretty good revenue
- Inmobi - Good revenue. Sometimes really dodgy ads.

I've experiemented with half a dozen others, but they provided insignificant revenue, or provided many bugs. But your mileage may vary.

Comment: Have you tried AdColony? Was considering using them since I keep hearing about them but I wasn't sure if their rates were good.